# How many 3-edge cycles in this directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, math

How to calculate how many 3-edge cycles are there in a strongly connected graph with n nodes and n*(n-1)/2 directed edges?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? Is this a directed or undirected graph? (Note that you have the wrong number of edges for an undirected graph.)

Comment: @RoryDaulton I said it is directed graph... Read carefully. I updated number of edges.

Comment: Yes, you did say "directed edges," I apologize. And you did correct the number of edges. But you still need to show what you have tried so far and say just where you are stuck. For example, have you tried graphs with 3, 4, and 5 nodes and counted the 3-edge cycles by hand, looking for a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The number you are looking for is not a constant, it depends on how the `n(n-1)/2` edges are placed and therefore you can not calculate it analytically. For example, the graph `G1=({1,2,3,4}, {(1,2), (2,3), (3,4}, (4,1), (2,1), (4,3)}` has `n = 4` nodes and `n(n-1)/2 = 6` edges, but contains no 3-edge cycle. On the contrary, the graph `G2=({1,2,3,4}, {(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,1), (3,1), (4,2)}` has two 3-edge cycles. This idea can be easily generalized to larger values of `n` and, moreover, it still holds if you disallow "reverse edges" (e.g., you could not have both `(1,2)` and `(2,1)` in `G1`). The example there is a bit more involved, and you actually need 5 nodes.

Therefore, it is only reasonable to look for an algorithm that computes the number of 3-edge cycles for a particular graph. A brute-force algorithm for `G=(V,E)` would be something like:

```
count = 0
for n1 in V:
  for n2 in V:
    for n3 in V:
      if E(n1, n2) and E(n2, n3) and E(n3, n1):
        count +=1
return(count / 3)  # because each triangle is counted 3 times
```

This could be optimized if you had the nodes and edges indexed, but I guess this goes beyond the scope of your question. I hope I'm understanding correctly your question and that my answer is of help.

Comment: Your first graph is not strongly connected. Furthermore, I count only 5 edges instead of 6.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to include the edge (4,1) in both examples. I have edited my answer and it's ok now. Sorry for the mistake.